# how to build a chrome extension like selenium IDE from scratch using Dart /Polymer?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-extension, dart-webui, guidance-automation-tool

How to build a chrome extension like selenium IDE  from scratch?

I am trying to get some information or write ups or links on how to create a chrome extension to record my selenium tests.

The extension should have a record option and a download option for downloading the scripts as in selenium IDE.

As my search results ,I am getting ideas to create a framework mostly.Any references on developing a recorder will help me in my task.

Referred Sites :

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

This question and search got in my mind after seeing the video here which says that we can develop an app using Dart or polymer

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps